# need help in making post request in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, curl

I need help in creating a post request in ruby. but i don't want to use `Net::Http` library. i just want to use curl commands to make post requests.

here is my existing code.

`

```
uri = URI.parse("http://example.com") 
header = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json','Accept' => "application/json"} 
req_data = {"name" => params[:user][:login], "pass" =>params[:user][:password]} 
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port) 
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header) 
request.body = req_data.to_json 
response = http.request(request)
```

`

Comment: i tried using `Net::HTTP` but i am not getting any response except HTTP::OK 200. but in fact it returns json

Comment: it returns like this `#<Net::HTTPOK:0xd08e898>`. but it doesn't reflected there and it gives a whole page html of url mentioned.

Comment: That `#<Net::HTTPOK:0xd08e898>` looks like a `Net::HTTPResponse` object. Have you tried calling `response.body`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a chance to execute command from user's input. With `Shellwords.escape` should be ok.

```
cmd_tpl = %{curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d "name=%s&pass=%s" %s}
cmd = cmd % [
              Shellwords.escape(URI.encode(params[:user][:login])),
              Shellwords.escape(URI.encode(params[:user][:password])),
              Shellwords.escape("http://example.com")
            ]
content = `#{cmd}`
```